# I cannot get my Health Potion to work in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a health potion for my game, however, it does not seem to work. My "if" statement does not seem to be getting called but if I get rid of the "if" statement a null reference appears. I am not sure what to do.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HealthPotion : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int heal = 25;
    [Header("Input")]
    public KeyCode healKey = KeyCode.Alpha1;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(healKey)) Heal();
       
    }
    
    void Heal()
    {
        PlayerHealth currentHealth = GetComponent<PlayerHealth>();
        if (currentHealth != null)
        {
        currentHealth.AddHealth(heal);
        Debug.Log("Heal");
        }
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Here is my Player Health code (which does not get called because of the problem occurring in my Health Potion code).

```
public void AddHealth(int heal)
    {
        currentHealth = currentHealth =+ heal;

        healthbar.SetCurrentHealth(currentHealth);

        if(currentHealth >= maxHealth)
        {
            currentHealth = maxHealth;
        }
        Debug.Log("Healed");
    }
```

Comment: Is the health potion component applied to the same game object as the player health?

Comment: This appears to be code id expect on the potion. Therefore it wont have the players health component. Even if itbdid. You then destroy it. So. Its gone

Comment: `GetComponent` only returns scripts that are attached to the same GameObject. For this to work, HealthPotion would have to be attached to the same GameObject as PlayerHealth.

Comment: Oh I see! would there be a better way to create the health potion so the script doesn't have to go on my Player? Or keep it the way it is, attach the script to the player, but when I destroy the health potion do something like Destroy (GameObject.FindWithTag("healthPotion")); so the Player doesnt get destroyed with it?

Comment: _You have to wait 2 minutes between drinking Health Potions and at least 30 minutes before going for a swim._